# My Bluetooth app crashes randomly with the error: Error receiving broadCast Intent

Tags: java, android

So i'm working on a Bluetooth app and it crashes randomly sometimes and I've yet to found a solution. Logcat complains at the line `if (device.getName().equals(pairedDevices.get(a))) {` but I don't understand what that has to do with the crash?

Any help is appreciated!

**Logcat:**

```
02-23 11:47:05.311 28011-28037/com.example.asabanov.powersupplytool E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xb91b9980
02-23 11:47:15.718 28011-28011/com.example.asabanov.powersupplytool E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.asabanov.powersupplytool, PID: 28011
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.bluetooth.device.action.FOUND flg=0x10 (has extras) } in com.example.asabanov.powersupplytool.BluetoothActivity$2@4d08f04
at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:934)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5845)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:687)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
at com.example.asabanov.powersupplytool.BluetoothActivity$2.onReceive(BluetoothActivity.java:129)
at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:915)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5845) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:687)
```

**BluetoothActivity:**

```
package com.example.asabanov.powersupplytool;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;

public class BluetoothActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnItemClickListener {

    public static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
    protected static final int SUCCESS_CONNECT = 0;
    protected static final int MESSAGE_READ = 1;
    ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter;
    ListView listView;
    BluetoothAdapter btAdapter;
    Set<BluetoothDevice> devicesArray;
    ArrayList<String> pairedDevices;
    ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> devices;
    IntentFilter filter;
    BroadcastReceiver receiver;
    String tag = "debugging";

    Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            super.handleMessage(msg);
            switch (msg.what) {
                case SUCCESS_CONNECT:
                    //do something
                    ConnectedThread connectedThread = new ConnectedThread((BluetoothSocket) msg.obj);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connect", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    String s = "Successfully connected";
                    connectedThread.write(s.getBytes());
                    break;
                case MESSAGE_READ:
                    byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                    String string = new String(readBuf);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connect", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bluetooth);

        init(); //initiate Bluetooth
        if (btAdapter == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No bluetooth detected on this device", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        } else {
            if (!btAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                turnOnBT();
            }

            pairedDevices=getPairedDevices();
            startDiscovery();
        }


    }

    private void startDiscovery() {
        btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        btAdapter.startDiscovery();

    }

    private void turnOnBT() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
    }

    private ArrayList getPairedDevices() {
        devicesArray = btAdapter.getBondedDevices();
        if (devicesArray.size() > 0) {
            //add devices in array to list array
            for (BluetoothDevice device : devicesArray) {
                pairedDevices.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
            }
        }
        return pairedDevices;
    }

    private void init() {
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 0);
        listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        pairedDevices = new ArrayList<String>();
        filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        devices = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();
        receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                String action = intent.getAction();
                if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                    BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

                    devices.add(device);
                    String s = "";

                    for (int a = 0; a < pairedDevices.size(); a++) {
                        if (device.getName().equals(pairedDevices.get(a))) { //log cat complains at this line
                            s = "Paired";
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    // matt-hp (paired)
                    listAdapter.add(device.getName() + " " + s + " " + "\n" + device.getAddress());
                } else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED.equals(action)) {
                    //run some code


                } else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)) {
                    //run some code

                } else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED.equals(action)) {
                    if (btAdapter.getState() == btAdapter.STATE_OFF) {
                        turnOnBT();
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED);
        registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
        filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
        registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
        filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);
        registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        registerReceiver(receiver, filter);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth must be enabled to continue", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        if (btAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
            btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        }

        if (listAdapter.getItem(position).contains("Paired")) {

            BluetoothDevice selectedDevice = devices.get(position);
            ConnectThread connect = new ConnectThread(selectedDevice);
            connect.start();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Device is paired", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Device is not paired", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;

        public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
            // Use a temporary object that is later assigned to mmSocket,
            // because mmSocket is final
            BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
            mmDevice = device;

            // Get a BluetoothSocket to connect with the given BluetoothDevice
            try {
                // MY_UUID is the app's UUID string, also used by the server code
                tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
            mmSocket = tmp;
        }

        public void run() {
            // Cancel discovery because it will slow down the connection
            btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

            try {
                // Connect the device through the socket. This will block
                // until it succeeds or throws an exception
                mmSocket.connect();
            } catch (IOException connectException) {
                // Unable to connect; close the socket and get out
                try {
                    mmSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException closeException) {
                }
                return;
            }

            // Do work to manage the connection (in a separate thread)
            mHandler.obtainMessage(SUCCESS_CONNECT, mmSocket).sendToTarget();
        }


        /**
         * Will cancel an in-progress connection, and close the socket
         */
        public void cancel() {
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
    }

    private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final InputStream mmInStream;
        private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

        public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
            mmSocket = socket;
            InputStream tmpIn = null;
            OutputStream tmpOut = null;

            // Get the input and output streams, using temp objects because
            // member streams are final
            try {
                tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
                tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }

            mmInStream = tmpIn;
            mmOutStream = tmpOut;
        }

        public void run() {
            byte[] buffer;   // buffer store for the stream
            int bytes; // bytes returned from read()

            // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
            while (true) {
                try {
                    // Read from the InputStream
                    buffer = new byte[1024];
                    bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
                    // Send the obtained bytes to the UI activity
                    mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer)
                            .sendToTarget();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        /* Call this from the main activity to send data to the remote device */
        public void write(byte[] bytes) {
            try {
                mmOutStream.write(bytes);
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }

        /* Call this from the main activity to shutdown the connection */
        public void cancel() {
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**MainActivity:**

```
package com.example.asabanov.powersupplytool;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BluetoothActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        Button Y10Button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        Y10Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View v){
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Y10.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        Button Y20Button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        Y20Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View v){
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Y20.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        Button SPAButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        SPAButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View v){
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SPA.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_about) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add some values to your `pairedDevices = new ArrayList<String>();` before you try `get()`

Comment: Hi.

what kind of values?

Answer (score 0):

BluetoothDevice object may be null. So you should check whether the object of BluetoothDevice is initialized successfully. I modified part of your code as following:

```
         BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                if(device != null) {
                   devices.add(device);
                   String s = "";

                   for (int a = 0; a < pairedDevices.size(); a++) {
                    if (device.getName().equals(pairedDevices.get(a))) { //log cat complains at this line
                        s = "Paired";
                        break;
                    }
                 }
                // matt-hp (paired)
                listAdapter.add(device.getName() + " " + s + " " + "\n" + device.getAddress());
              }
```

Comment: Hi. I added the code, but It still crashes with the same error message and pointing to the same line.

Comment: Try to use device address instead of device name. To get device name call getAddress() method on the bluetooth device object. On your arraylist object pairedDevices store only device address. You are storing both device name and device address.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `device.getName()` returns null, thus the exception is thrown when you call the `.equals()` method on a null object.

You can check the following question to find a solution to your problem -
[android BluetoothDevice.getName() return null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26290640/android-bluetoothdevice-getname-return-null)

Comment: This sounds promising! Since i'm fairly new to java, and don't understand everything yet, how would I implement the solution into my code that I posted above?